# Filling a specific shape within a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array and would like to increase the values of a specific part of it by 1. A simple example is:

Empty array:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

We decide to base our area on e.g. 3 points ( [[0,2], [2,4], [3,1]] ) but the number of points could be higher as well:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

And fill the shape within this polygone with ones:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

How can I do this in an automated way? Something like:

```
arr = np.zeros([5,5])
shapePoints = [[0,2], [2,4], [3,1]]
valueToFill = 1
arr = fillShape(arr, shapePoints, valueToFill)
```

... where *fillShape* is the function that I am searching for. That must exist in numpy?

Comment: Whether the number of vertices you are trying to fill is fixed (Vertices:Three, Shape:Triangle in this case) or can it change in the future?

Comment: Yes, it can change - minimum of 3 and maximum of possibly 20 or so

Comment: Have you tried Cairo, I do not know exactly why you want this, but cairo allows creating surfaces. http://www.cairographics.org/

Comment: It is in the end not so much about the plotting but about creating the values of the np array ... I can plot all my shapes using PolygonPatch but I want to map them onto an np array in order to do further calculations on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit has a implementation for such a polygon drawing algorithm. 
See [skimage.draw.polygon](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.polygon)

Edit: concrete code for the question

```
from skimage.draw import polygon, polygon_perimeter
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((5, 5))
shapePoints = np.array([[0,2], [2,4], [3,1]])
points_r, points_c = shapePoints[:, 0], shapePoints[:, 1]
interior_r, interior_c = polygon(points_r, points_c)
perimeter_r, perimeter_c = polygon_perimeter(points_r, points_c)
arr[perimeter_r, perimeter_c] = 3
arr[points_r, points_c] = 2
arr[interior_r, interior_c] = 1
```

Note that this produces a different result than the one in the question in order to illustrate the difference between interior and perimeter.

```
>>> arr
array([[0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 3., 0.],
       [0., 3., 1., 1., 2.],
       [0., 2., 3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: please consider adding the solution here, for the benefit of everyone

Comment: That would be just copy-pasting the documentation example. Is that encouraged here?

Comment: better than not having anything, IMO :)